# Partitioning table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I'm having table like

```
empid,empname,cityname,statename,countryname.
```

how to split this table structure?

Regards
Bharathi

Answer (score 1):

This is a very nice article on creating partitioned tables

[Partitioned Tables in SQL Server 2005](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/partitioned-tables-in-sql-server-2005/)

The question everyone is asking is, how many records do you have in this table and what might the particular reason be for partitioning?

The table structure does not seem overly complicated, and you have made no mention of record count or indexes.

If you do not have to many records, I cannot see any reason to partition the table...